# CPU Usage disabled in performance profiler VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2019, profiling

We are running an ASP.Net WebForms solution on .Net Framework 4.8 in Visual Studio 2019.
In previous versions of VS we could do CPU Usage performance profiling. However, now it is disabled. Any help in determining why would be appreciated

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

I have tried Setting the start up project to 4.8.1
It is also set to start as current page. I have also done several searches and unable to find any explanations for this issue that have resolved my problem

Comment: Their documentation says the appropriate "workload" needs to be installed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2022.  I guess check your Visual Studio installation to make sure you have the proper tools installed.

Comment: I have the appropriate components installed. If i create a new .Net Framework 4.8 Web Forms project the CPU profiling option becomes available for that project